# How to search certain characters based on their unicode number?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I would like to search certain characters and replace them. They can be separated by their unicode number. For example, below 3 characters has different unicode number.

```
á(#xe1), ⓐ(#x24d0), (#x1d4b6)
```

What if I want to search characters between the range #x1d000 to #x1dfff, and then I will use regxp replace to add a double quote("") for each of these characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can enter Unicode characters by their hexadecimal codes using the key binding `C-x 8 C-m` (the command is called `insert-char`).  So type `C-x 8 C-m`, enter `1d000`, and then hit `RET` to insert the character with Unicode code point 1d000.

Then we can use this to search and replace.

- Type `C-M-%` to run the command `query-replace-regexp`
- For the search expression, enter `[`, then `C-x 8 C-m 1d000 RET` , then `-`, and then `C-x 8 C-m 1dfff RET`, and finally `]`.  That is, search for any character in the range between 1d000 and 1dfff.  (This is similar to the "normal" regexp `[a-z]`, which matches all characters between `a` and `z`, i.e. all lowercase characters.)
- For the replace expression, enter `"\&"`.  `\&` is a special sequence for inserting the text matched by the search expression, so we're going to wrap every matching character in double quotes.
- Then, hit `y` to replace matches one by one, or `!` to replace all remaining matches.